# Speed up creation of random data

Tags: python, random

I have written this very simple script to create some random data for machine learning.

```
from random import randint

f = open('2014-07-17-1M_testdata_1Mx500.cvs', 'w', 50000000) #50MB write buffer
for i in range(1000000): #num rows
    for i2 in range(500): #entries per row
        f.write(str(randint(0,1000000))) #Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b.
        if(i2 != 499): #entries per row - 1
            f.write(",")
    f.write("\n")
    if(i != 0 and i % 100000 == 0):
        print(str(i) + " lines written")
f.close
```

However, I've noticed that one CPU core is used with 100% load and the creation of data takes much longer than disk speed allows.
For creating large datasets (100+ GB), is there an easy way to speed this up? Some faster random library perhaps?

Comment: Printing 500 million entries seems like a slow task to be done by a single core, particularly in python. I'm not sure the "random" is the bottleneck, but disk I/O.

Comment: I've used iostat to monitor disk i/o, and it was idle most of the time

Comment: Ok, I didn't look up the implementation of the write buffer. It does only write those 50M every few seconds, but I guess it the way the buffer is filled might be ineffective.

Comment: Make sure to tell us what you figure out, I'm interested to discover your eventual solution!

Comment: Why are you using CSV files for datasets as big as 100 GB?  Why not use a binary format?

Comment: The real data will be in text format as well, so measuring how the application (Apache Spark) handles these is part of tests as well. That's why I can't use binary in this case.

Comment: Reducing the buffer size should help a fair bit. Try just leaving it at the default. It should help let the Python code to execute at the same time the operating system writes out the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure Python is a tough one, but luckily there are efficient Python libraries that can help speed things up. [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) is a good one:

```
import numpy
import numpy.random

f = open('2014-07-17-1M_testdata_1Mx500.csv', 'w', 50000000)

for i in range(1000):
    m = numpy.random.random_integers(0, 1000000, (1000, 500))
    numpy.savetxt(f, m, delimiter=',')

f.close()
```

Running on my MacBook Pro, the code is definitely bound by writing to the disk instead of CPU,
so this seems to do the trick.